# Android app is running but internet is going down what method is called?

Tags: android

Android app is running but internet is going down what method is called:`onPause(),onResume(),onDestroy()`??

Comment: You would catch this in a Broadcast Receiver rather than the activity life cycle..

Answer (score 3):

Neither, `Activity` lifecycle methods have nothing to do with the connection state.